# Quelle est la difference entre « être malade » et « se porter mal » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, santé-et-médecine

Quelle est la difference entre « être malade » et « se porter mal » ?

Le premier est-il moins grave que le dernier, ou est-ce que ce sont des synonymes ?

Comment: On dit en général plutôt "mal se porter" que "se porter mal", même si dans les formes conjuguées "mal" repasse après "porter".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *Être malade* : avoir une maladie connue et soignable.
- *Se porter mal* : ne pas se sentir en bonne santé, mais ne pas savoir quel en est la raison.

Parfois les gens mélangent les deux expressions pour dire qu'ils sont fatigués, stressés, *qu'ils se sentent mal* sans pouvoir définir exactement le cause de leur mal être.

Comment: Être malade ne veut pas forcement dire qu'on peut être soigné. Certaines maladies sont incurables, certaines n'ont même pas de traitements.

Comment: @ThomasFrancois -- *Soigner* veut dire mettre à disposition du patient tous les moyens thérapeutiques connus pour lutter contre sa maladie. Les Unités de Soins Palliatifs soignent les malades incurables en mettant tout en œuvre pour éviter la douleur et permettre un apaisement face à la peur de la mort.

Comment: Merci pour l'info, je ne savais pas

Comment: être malade signifie qu'on a une pathologie, avec certains symptômes. Ensuite, le diagnostic peut être difficile ou impossible, la maladie non connue (et encore moins soignable). Le sens est très similaire entre les 2.

Comment: "mal se porter" plutôt que "se porter mal".

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE - Il y a une 'lecture' différente entre "mal se [com]porter" et "se porter mal[ade]", de plus "mal je me porte" n'est pas usuel, seulement pour donner un effet  théâtral ou ampoulé (http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/ampoul%C3%A9 §2).

Comment: Tu as mal compris. Ce n'est pas "mal je me porte", c'est "mal se porter" qui est la désignation infinitive de: "Je me porte mal".

Answer (score -1):

*se porter mal* est peu employé, on emploie plutôt *se porter bien/ ne pas se porter bien*.

Le sens vise autant les pathologies que l'état physique général (*être / ne pas être en bonne forme physique*).

*être malade*: concerne seulement les pathologies (connues ou inconnues, curables ou incurables). Cela signifie aussi être fou, être dingue (faire des choses anormales).

*se sentir mal*: plus fréquent: indique qu'on ressent une possible maladie, ou faiblesse, qui peut être transitoire.

*se porter pâle*: se déclarer malade (réellement, ou à dessein), pour avertir qu'on ne pourra pas assister à une réunion, un travail, etc.

Comment: "Mal se porter" est employé par contre. Est-ce qu'il va bien? Non, il se porte plutôt mal.